# Can I bypass login in quickbooks online v3 and use API

Tags: quickbooks

I am trying to integrate quickbooks online v3 with c#.
In earlier version I could connect with appid and token.
Current version I would like to bypass the login and use API. Token is generated after logging in to qbsite.

Answer (score 1):

**No, this isn't possible** (for what should be very, very obvious security reasons - why would anyone want to allow any person access to all of their companies financial data without any sort of login/authentication mechanism what-so-ever?).

The new v3 APIs use OAuth for authentication. The end-user is required to log in *once* to generate the OAuth tokens and authorize your app to access QuickBooks data.

After that authorization, you can use those tokens to access QuickBooks data any time you want.

This pretty much exactly mirrors the old qbXML connection ticket method that was previously available.